Android aws s3 file upload real-time progress check
Is there a way to upload a file using Android AWS S3 transferUtility within a Worker and check onProgressChanged in the TransferListener in real time from the app?
fun uploadWithTransferUtility(
    uri: List<CroppingImage>, context: Context, makePostRequestDto: MakePostRequestDto
) {

    val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

    // Constraints.Builder()를 통해 실행 제약을 설정할 수 있음
    val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
        // 네트워크가 연결되어있는 상태일 때
        .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
        .build()

    val data = Data.Builder().putStringArray(Constant.KET_IMAGE_URI, uri.map { it.imageUri.toString() }.toTypedArray()).build()


    val workRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(AwsS3FileUploadWorker::class.java)
        .setConstraints(constraints)
        .setInputData(data)
        .addTag("aws_s3_file_upload")
        .build()

    workManager.enqueue(workRequest)
}

